# SQLalchemy and Flask-admin - performance issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I don't understand to Flask-Admin and sql queries which it uses. I have problem with performance but main reason is that unreasonable queries are called.

I have model:

```
class Hotel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "hotel"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('country.id'))
    area_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('area.id'))
    ....
    photos = relationship(Photo, backref=backref('hotel', lazy='select'), lazy='dynamic')
    terms = relationship(Term, backref=backref('hotel', lazy='noload'), lazy='dynamic')
```

and if I want to read information for one hotel in Flask-administration there are several queries which are suspicious

Eg. following query is called for million times with argue, which doesn't have sense

```
[Sun Apr 13 17:31:22 2014] [error] INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT photo.id AS photo_id, photo.hotel_id AS     photo_hotel_id, photo.filename AS photo_filename
[Sun Apr 13 17:31:22 2014] [error] FROM photo
[Sun Apr 13 17:31:22 2014] [error] WHERE %s = photo.hotel_id
[Sun Apr 13 17:31:22 2014] [error] 2014-04-13 17:31:22,549 INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1L,)
```

and another query is called without filtering for chosen hotel.id and the query doesn't finish till timeout and it is useless again

```
    [Sun Apr 13 17:31:22 2014] [error] INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT term.id AS term_id, term.hotel_id AS term_hotel_id, ...
[Sun Apr 13 17:31:22 2014] [error] FROM term
```

Please could you give some hint what' happened in my admin, I realy don't know what I should improve.

Thank you